# CSRF Basics with SSL & CSRF Relationship

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, csrf, csrf-protection

I am trying to implement CSRF and SSL(they are not entirely dependent) and listing below my understanding on the topic for having a proof of understanding.
Please feel free to correct me about the understanding. 
We see CSRF Token in almost all of our secure applications.

**How Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) works :**

You logged into your bank account(eg. SBI or JPMC) and are looking at your accounts or it's just sitting their opened on your browser just because you got busy.
Now you receive an email may be text/image or anything on the next tab. The moment the email is received functions like onload etc other java script function may trigger a GET/PUT/POST request from your browser without you knowing about it.
Now things to note is that CSRF can't actually read anything from your secured webpage because the moment you have a proper SSL the secure pages are encrypted. And also CSRF can't steal your credentials. As a matter of fact it can't find out the CSRF token kept inside hidden tag inside secure website because its encrypted. It works only after you have authenticated yourself with the website and it fires requests which tricks the server into thinking that the request in coming from the browser you just logged into and thus server work as per the received request.

Now with hacker trying to open a CSRF attack, it tricks the browser to send url:

```
<img src="https://www.bankWebsite.com/transfer?amount=1000&amp;destination=8990">
```

Thus without you knowing, from a session which is authenticated by you, a request is fired telling to transfer amount of 1000 in account number 8990 n BOOM you were robbed for 1000 bucks just like that.

**How to protect youself:** 
CSRF protection can be done in a couple of ways:
1) Verifying the origin of request from header
2) Verifying the target of the request
3) CSRF token

**How CSRF token protection works:**

The CSRf token in present in the header/cookie. So when the hacker tricks the browser into sending the request to the server, the token is present only in the header and not in form submitted. So when the server goes to check whether the CSRF token received, it tries to match the CSRF token from the header with that received from the form/request. If it's not present/doesn't match then server identifies that it's an attack and stops the request from penetrating further.

Request you all to please correct me if my understanding about the CSRF attack, protection is correct or not ?
Also does it mean **without** proper implementation of SSL, CSRF is of no use ?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @Andreas purpose is to know whether the understanding about the need of CSRF and protection against CSRF is correct or not so that the designing can be commenced for the project.

Comment: [OWASP: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF)

Comment: What you described regarding the CSRF looks good but CSRF and SSL are two different issues. CSRF is to verify that the requests(for add/edit/delete any request) are being originated from actual user not by an attacker. However, what you think regarding SSL implementation is a must. If the application does not use SSL, CSRF token can be theft(but if not SSL is not implemented, an attacker can also do more stuff comparing to that such as sniffing the request and get credentials). Please also refer goo.gl/qkGU9 and goo.gl/iUEHp.

Comment: @SavanGadhiya thanks for reading it out and giving the first valuable comment I was looking for. Reading your comment hit me with another thought. Have update the question as well

Comment: I am not sure why the question got a downvote. I am writing a design document and wanted to cover all raised scenarios. Stack overflow should not remain just a hub of codes to copy paste but develop understanding as well.

Comment: Regarding your last update "Also does it mean without proper implementation of SSL, CSRF is of no use?".
Both are necessary to prevent the application from security issues.
In the case of SSL is not inplace:
1. CSRF is implemented - Attacker need to sniff the CSRF token first and then can craft CSRF page to exploit CSRF issue.
2. CSRF is not implemented - Attacker can craft CSRF page(as do not use CSRF token) to exploit CSRF issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Request you all to please correct me if my understanding about the CSRF attack, protection is correct or not ?

Yes

> Also does it mean without proper implementation of SSL, CSRF is of no use ?

If you send the token to and from the client in plain text (instead of encrypting it with SSL) then it can be intercepted by the attacker.

If the attacker knows what token to put in the form data, the protection is gone.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the confirmation